# How to read the refresh_token generated in OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: .net, oauth, owin, refresh-token

Is there way to read the refresh_token generated by my OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider on login? I see that you can read the accesss_token by implementing the following method:

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
{
    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

however the refresh token doesn't seem to exist in the OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext. **Is there somewhere I can read the refresh token for logging/troubleshooting purposes?**

Background:

My client is having issues with refresh tokens on their network (which I'm not allowed to access). They previously had issues where a network-wide security appliance they have on premises was overwriting my applications access_token in flight.

I'm fairly certain it is doing the same with the refresh_token, but they're denying it. I would like to add logging on what refresh_token was generated, and what refresh token was used to attempt a refresh. That way we can better see if it is being modified at some point in the login/refresh life-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I was looking in the wrong place. The refresh token is generated, and can be read in, your implementation of AuthenticationTokenProvider, in the Create method:

```
public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{
    context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20));
    context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());

    string refreshToken = context.Token;
}
```